# Should there be an "Edit question Tags Privilege"

Tags: support, privileges

[This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123630/how-can-i-improve-this-set-of-queries-in-php) Question Should be tagged as a SQL question.

Should there be an "Edit question Tags Privilege"

(Is there currently one?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to edit tags by editing the post or by clicking the "edit tags" link that shows up when you mouse over the tags:

[image]

Comment: Clicking to edit the Post allowed me to add the Tag. (Thanks) The Mouse over "Edit Tag link" was a link to "Edit tag wiki"

Comment: @Morons I added a screenshot for the "edit tags" link. I don't remember what the rep threshold is before it shows up, though. I think you should see it if you mouse over area to the right of the tags, but I'm not 100% sure.